# Getting stuck on a While Loop using BufferedReader

Tags: java, sockets

I've been having a problem with using a while loop surrounding a BufferedReader in Java. I'm doing some experiments with Sockets.

My current code:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(this.IP);
        SocketAddress socketaddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, this.port);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(socketaddress);

        if(socket.isConnected()){

            Executor.logger.info("Connection to proxy established!");

        }
        else {

            Executor.logger.warning("Connection to proxy failed!");
            socket.close();
            return;

        }

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String temp2;
        while((temp2 = in.readLine()) != null){

            Executor.logger.info("Running query says " + temp2);

        }
```

But no matter what I've tried the code will not progress to the next line. It does not spam my logger with anything, it just suddenly stops and gets stuck.

This is client-side only and I am not in control of the receiver server-side.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edits**

The server is a command-line that accepts a command with variables and returns with a code that tells you the outcome of what you just did. However, when you first connect it returns something like message, blank line, message, blank line which is the loop currently getting stuck.

Comment: It *blocks* on `readLine()` because it's waiting for data. The connection isn't closed, so `readLine()` doesn't return `null`, but there isn't any data coming in, so it keeps waiting for data to arrive. Presumably the server is waiting for some input from you until it returns more data. You also need another thread for the writer so you can receive data and send data at the same time.

Comment: Is there any way to detect when the BufferedReader is empty? I do need the code to progress as it based inside a constructor.

Comment: You should use a threaded listener like DataFetcher: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java

Comment: Inside a constructor is not the right place for that code. You still need another thread to write data back to the server because when `readLine()` blocks, the reading thread won't do anything.

Comment: As far as I am aware the server only returns the response code from input data. Are you saying I am going to need the reader to run continuously separate from writing to the outputstream?

Comment: If your protocol is "client sends a line, server responds with a line" then you can put them in the same loop alternatively (`send` - `read` - `send` etc.), but you need to know the *protocol* i.e. what the server expects. If the server can send data without receiving a message from the client (such as in a chat application), then you need separate threads for reader/writer.

Comment: (I'll add this to the main question) The server is a Query Interface that accepts commands via the console (or hopefully this socket) and responds with a function code (e.g code=0 msg=ok would be for success). However, when you first connect to it the server returns message, blank line, message, blank line. This is the part that gets stuck.

Comment: `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you're testing it. An exception would have been thrown. Don't write pointless code.

Answer (score 1):

After testing I have found an alternative variable that can be used to detect whether the BufferedReader is full or not.

If you change the ((temp2 = in.readLine()) != null) from this code:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    String temp2;
    while((temp2 = in.readLine()) != null){

        Executor.logger.info("Running query says " + temp2);

    }
```

And use the boolean (in.ready()) instead:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        out.write("login " + this.user + " " + this.password);
        out.flush();

        String temp2;
        while(in.ready()){

            temp2 = in.readLine();

            Executor.logger.info("Running query says " + temp2);

        }
```

It will stop the loop when the BufferedRead has no more data to read and can be re-initialised again whenever necessary by copying the loop again.

Comment: This will still block if less than a complete line is available.

Comment: My tests of having it written with no input seem to work and the code just skips. The method reads: "Tells whether this stream is ready to be read. A buffered character stream is ready if the buffer is not empty..."

Comment: I suggest you read some networking tutorials to find out how to properly do network IO. This is not the correct way, even if it may work you for a particular case. Or you can learn the wrong way and then at some point in the future encounter bugs because of it.

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself if you have a better method. This is the only way that I've found (research or experimentation) that works and have no current alternatives.